# "Recursive Print Statement" with Nodelets

Tags: ros, roscpp, nodelet, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently converted a few of my nodes to nodelets to take advantage of zero-copy message passing. Even though I have converted all of the standard ROS logging macros (e.g. `ROS_ERROR()`) to the nodelet-aware equivalents (e.g. `NODELET_ERROR()`), I get the following warning printed to my terminal:

> Warning: recursive print statement has occurred.  Throwing out recursive print.

After this message prints it appears that the logging macros cease to function. Has anyone else encountered this message when using nodelets? How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9989/%22recursive-print-statement%22-with-nodelets/) by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 524 on 2011-05-18

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are open tickets on this issue:

- [ros-pkg 4854](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4854)
- [ros-pkg 4855](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4855)

The first ticket includes some suggested workarounds.  My understanding is that this problem still exists and needs to be fixed.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2011-05-18**:
Thanks for the link. Switching from using standalone nodelets to using a manager fixed the problem.